# How can I draw an CGImageRef context on the screen?

Tags: iphone, uikit, core-graphics

I have a beautiful CGImageRef context, which I created the whole day to get alpha values ;)

It's defined like that:

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData, pixWidth, pixHeiht 8, pixWidth, NULL, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
```

So for my understanding, that context represents somehow my image. But "virtually", non-visible somewhere in memory.

Can I stuff that in an UIImageView or draw that directly to the screen? I guess that alpha would be converted to grayscale or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `UIImage` by calling:

`+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage`

and then draw the `UIImage` using:

`- (void)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point`

Answer (score 2):

Go look at `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()`, that can give you a CGImageRef from your bitmap context. You can then draw that using the CGContext... functions or make a UIImage using `+[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize size = ...;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
...
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
...
CGPoint pt = ...;
[img drawAtPoint:pt];
```